# How to restrict div's height in certain project

Tags: html, css

I have 3 columns layout where middle column's part has problem with its height.
Generally, it is a chat app.
The classes are:
for a container with these three columns (I decided for a grid like this to have equal height of columns):

```
display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 360px auto 300px;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
```

Left and right columns are less important, however it must be told that left displays a list of users; the length of the list is subject to change (one can filter users). The right column has static content (in the sense of size);

middle column:

```
 position: relative;
```

and in this middle column I have 3 divs, where the second is a headache

Top div (its height is constant);

```
height: calc(
            var(--users-search-height) + (var(--users-search-wrapper-height) - var(--users-search-height)) / 2
        );
```

Bottom div (height also constant)

```
height: var(--users-search-wrapper-height);
       
        bottom: 0;
```

When initially rendered, usually left column content is highest and bottom div visually aligns with its content. When one filtrates users, the bottom div of middle columns aligns visually with bottom part of right column. And it is perfectly OK.
The problem appears when chat messages appear in the middle div of the middle columns. As long as these are few it is not an issue, but soon the middle div becomes large and barges. Consequently, the middle column has higher height and bottom div is more and more down, what kills the layout. I would like the middle div of the middle column to get its own scroll on reaching a specific height and to not exceed the height, but it seems to be enormously complicated.

Now, the style for middle div is as follows:

```
max-height: calc(
            100% - var(--users-search-wrapper-height) -
                (var(--users-search-height) + (var(--users-search-wrapper-height) - var(--users-search-height)) / 2)
        );

        height: as above;

        overflow-y: scroll;
```

But it does not work, the content height increases with new messages (though scroll is active and some of the content is 'behind' the scroll). I suspect it has something to do with the fact that column's container does not have fixed height in px. But it can not. I have also tried to style the middle column as flex or grid, but always there was the same effect. Perhaps one can work it out with JS, but would rather have stricty CSS solution. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's useless to set `overflow-y: scroll` to the `div` element that has a large size. This property (`overflow`) presupposes a lower height than it will have. So to fix your code, you have to wrap that `div` element with, for example, `<div class="wrap">...<div>` with the following properties:

```css
.wrap {
 height: calc(100vh - var(--top-div-height) - var(--bottom-div-height));
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Where `var(--top-div-height)` and `var(--bottom-div-height)` are the heights of the top and bottom divs elements.

Comment: But vh doesn't do here, whole column exceeds screen height.